# Change element by date with CSS

Tags: php, html, css

I'm looking at using a large image in the background of a home page and would like the image to change every day, using CSS only. I'll obviously have a set of images to call in, not sure how may yet. It would be good if they could loop through though.

Would it be worth using a sprite and shifting the position on a 24 hour loop? I'm sure there's a cleaner way...

Many thanks!

Comment: If you want to use pure css, why is your question labeled php?

Comment: If you want the answer to be "using CSS only", why tag the question as PHP?

Comment: One solution is to set a class with PHP, indicating the time (or even javascript) and then you use animations to change the background. You make the animation to have 24*60*60 seconds.

Comment: That's a long animation !

Comment: @deKajoo That's the goal, and they are actually cpu-friendly and work with almost-pure css.

Comment: I was trying to get to an answer that avoided JS primarily; not really familiar with it. I presumed I'd need php somewhere though so I put it in the tags.
Thanks Ismael.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot to this using CSS *only*.

You can of course create 24 classes, one for each hour (or day, or whatever you like), each having a separate image background:

```
.hour01 { background:url('image-01.png'); }
.hour02 { background:url('image-02.png'); }
```

etc....

But you need either a server side language (such as PHP) or a client side language (javascript) to check what date/time it is and based on that, switch the CSS class of the body element.

Comment: Thanks!… Out of interest; what defines the 'time'; server timezone, client timezone or what?

Comment: @CentaurMagenta that depends on where you fetch the time.  If you use Javascript, it's the date/time on the client that counts.  If you use a server side language, it's the date/time on the server.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that only in css but if you add some js it's doable :

```
today = new Date(); // will return 1,2,...,7 correpsonding to week days

if (today.getDay()  === 1){
     document.getElementById("background").className += 'mondayStyle';
}
if (today.getDay()  === 2){
     document.getElementById("background").className += 'tuersdayStyle';
}
...
```

**Edit:**

If you have not exactly 7 images (but less than ~30) you can do :

```
var nbOfImages = 12;
numDay = (today.getDate())% nbOfImages;  // day of the month modulus nbOfImages
if (numDay  === 1){
     document.getElementById("background").className += 'tuersdayStyle';
}
...
```

Comment: Thanks! I should really get up to scotch with JS.

Comment: : D
Glad it helped, you can confirm the answer if your problem is solved.